# Python и сокеты

Tags: python

Я написал сервер и клиент для передачи простой строки в python. Проблема в установке подключения. Видите ли, библиотека socket сообщает, что мой IP: xx.xx.xx.xx, а сайт 2ip.ru, Windows, yandex говорят, что IP: yy.yy.yy.yy.

```
## Определение IP
import socket as sct
print(sct.gethostbyname(sct.gethostname()))
```

Друг подключался и к xx.xx.xx.xx и yy.yy.yy.yy - ничего не выходило, в программе сервера подключений не было обнаружено, порт был открыт, сервер принимает все IP. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: ну очевидно вопрос не в питоне, нужно приобрести выделенный ip или использовать сервисы вроде динднс

Comment: а xx.xx.xx.xx это просто локальный айпи, который за роутером (обычно это 192.168.0.2) или серый айпи, который выдается провайдером (обычно это что то вида 10.0.3.30). В этих случаях нужно реальный айпи. Не нужно от людей скрывать айпи, все равно вычислят:)

Comment: @KoVadim а как определить реальный IP?

Comment: его как раз возвращает 2ip.ru. Но если это не адрес на роутере, то это малополезно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопавшись в интернете, я нашёл ещё один способ определения IP адреса, который РАБОТАЕТ с моим компьютером! Это значение Ipv4 в команде ipconfig.